# Running Datastore queries on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How we can run queries from local machine to remote app deployed on Google app engine? (not talking for admin web console)

Traditionally we can connect to remote db as easy as local, just by using remote IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Appengine Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi) to access the appengine services from any Java application. For example, you can use Remote API to access a production datastore from an app running on your local machine. You can also use Remote API to access the datastore of one App Engine app from a different App Engine app.

Please refer this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi

Comment: so this is not possible to run queries for example from my local console? I need to run my local app to connect remote DS?!

Comment: No, you would be running the remote_api console, no your local app follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi) provided by @NNJ

Comment: @Nav Not sure about Java. But In Python SDK, We can use [Remote API Shell](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi#using_the_remote_api_shell) to access the production datastore from our console.